# MDX aggregate over lower level

Tags: aggregate, mdx, mondrian

I need to aggregate over upper level with filter on members from lower one.
It is for report that present sales in every year with filter on one specific month.
This is example for FoodMart database and Product Dimension with levels:

1. [Product Family]
2. [Product Department]

---

MDX:

```
WITH
MEMBER [Measures].[Unit Sales Calculated] AS
    Aggregate(
        Intersect(
            Descendants(
                [Product].CurrentMember,
                [Product].[Product Department],
                SELF
            ),
            [Filtered Product Department]
        ),
        [Measures].[Unit Sales]
    )
SET [Filtered Product Department] AS
Except(
    [Product].[Product Department].Members,
    [Product].[Drink].[Alcoholic Beverages]
)
SELECT
 NON EMPTY [Measures].[Unit Sales Calculated] ON COLUMNS,
 NON EMPTY [Product].[Product Family].Members) ON ROWS
FROM [Sales]
```

This solution works but **performance is rather poor**.
Is there **better** way to write this query?